# Variable in Array Not Working

Tags: taxonomy, terms, array, variables, query-variable

I having an issue getting a variable to work for one of my arguments in a query. I am using a custom post type and category name as terms to determine which categories are displayed.

When I hardcode the values into the terms it works fine, but when I use a variable it doesn't seem to work.

**This code works:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sparknz',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'sparknz_gardens',
            'field'     => 'name',
            'terms'     => array ( 'The A Team', 'The B Team', 'The C Team' ),
        )
    )
);
```

**But this does not (notice variable in terms):**

```
$my_term_names = "'The A Team','The B Team','The C Team'";

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sparknz',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'sparknz_gardens',
            'field'     => 'name',
            'terms'     => array( $my_term_names ),
        )
    )
);
```

I need the terms to be a variable. Any Ideas?

**Just an update as to why I am using a string as a variable. I am using `array_intersect` to pick out similarities in two arrays:**

```
$my_user_array  = array( "c" => $user_array );
$my_cat_array   = array( "d" => $category_array );
$myresult       = array_intersect( $my_user_array, $my_cat_array );
$my_term_names  = implode( ",", $myresult );

echo $$my_term_names;
```

Not sure if there is another way to do this?

Comment: `$my_term_names` is a single string, your original array is has multiple indices containing strings. Even though your string has commas in it PHP will not separate them into values. Why name just make `$my_term_names` into an array with 3 string values?

Comment: Hi Howdy_McGee, I am using a string because I am using 'array_intersect' and then listing results as a string.

Comment: Sorry Howdy Mcgee I spoke too soon. I am still stuck with the same issue because of my 'array_intersect' statement giving back a string.

Comment: @aido14 If your question has been answered, could you please accept the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is represented as one continuous string:

`$my_term_names = "'The A Team','The B Team','The C Team'";`

You want these terms to be an array:

`$my_term_names = array( 'The A Team', 'The B Team', 'The C Team' );`

Now you need to remove the `array()` from your terms query.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sparknz',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sparknz_gardens',    // taxonomy name
            'field'    => 'name',               // term_id, slug or name
            'terms'    => $my_term_names,       // Terms array (defined above)
        )
    )
);
```

**Edit. 10/19/2016**

I realize you want to find the similarities between multiple arrays using `array_intersect();` however, you need to stop trying to bring everything back into string format once you have your similarities located. `array_intersect();` takes multiple arrays, finds the similarities, and returns a new array, containing the similar values between the multiple arrays specified.

**Example #1 `array_intersect()` example**

```
$array1 = array( "a" => "green", "red", "blue" );
$array2 = array( "b" => "green", "yellow", "red" );
$result = array_intersect( $array1, $array2 );
print_r( $result );
```

**The above example will output:**

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
)
```

If you plan on retrieving multiple terms from your `tax_query`, the `terms` argument of the `tax_query` needs to be in **array format** . Not string format.

**Here's an updated example for your situation. I've used simple variable names to get the point across:**

```
$terms_array_1 = array( 'The B Team', 'The D Team', 'The A Team' );
$terms_array_2 = array( 'The A Team', 'The B Team', 'The C Team' );

$similar_terms = array_intersect( $terms_array_1, $terms_array_2 );

print_r( $similar_terms );

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'sparknz',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'sparknz_gardens',    // taxonomy name
            'field'    => 'name',               // term_id, slug or name
            'terms'    => $similar_terms,       // Term Names array (similarities between array1 and array2)
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi Michael, I spoke too soon. I am using an array_intersect which gives returns a string. Is there any way you know where I could return something that I can use in my 'terms'?

Comment: `array_intersect()` returns an **array** containing all the values of `array1` that are present in all the arguments. *Note that keys are preserved.*

Answer (score 2):

PHP interprets those arrays differently. In the first example you're asking WP_Query to get posts
**by 3** term slugs and in the second example you're assigning the array a value of 1 string. If we were to print the two arrays it would look like this:

**Your Example 1:**

```
'terms' => array(
    [0] => 'The A Team',
    [1] => 'The B Team',
    [2] => 'The C Team'
)
```

**Your Example 2:**

```
'terms' => array(
    [0] => '\'The A Team','The B Team','The C Team\''
)
```

PHP thinks that you're assigning it a single string, even if there's commas in the string itself it is an absolute string. What you'll need to do is make the variable itself an array.

```
$my_term_names = array(
    'The A Team',
    'The B Team',
    'The C Team'
)

'terms' => $my_term_names
```

Comment: Thank you very much Howdy, work perfectly. Made perfect sense with your explanation too. Awesome!!

Comment: I did get an error because of missing colon ; at end of array, if you want to edit

Comment: Can I use str_split() ?

Comment: @aido14 - [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) may be a better solution to whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Howdy, but explode needs to be a string to start off with. Looking at my code can you see a way I could make this work and give an example?